# For loop not being executed second time around in a while loop

Tags: c++, for-loop

I'm just a beginner in C++. I'm writing small and simple program that prints a series of integers between two user-specified integers.

At the end, the program will re-run the while loop if the user returns 1, but when that happens the program will not print the series of numbers again (the for loop doesn't work).

Here's the source code:

```
int main(void)
{
    int num1, num2;
    int doContinue = 1;

    while (doContinue == 1)
    {
        cout << "Please enter two integers, the first being the smallest: ";

         do { //does everything in curly braces while the user inputs the numbers wrong...
                cin >> num1 >> num2;

                if (num1 > num2)
                    {
                        cout << "Your first number was bigger than the second.\nTry again!: ";
                    }

            } while (num1 > num2);//... but once it's not wrong, break out of this do loop

        //at this point the input has been checked, so we can proceed to print the series

        for(int num1; num1 <= num2; num1++)
            {   
                cout << num1 << " \n";
            }

        cout << "Would you like to compute another series of integers? 1=yes, anything else=no: ";
        cin >> doContinue;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code exhibits undefined behavior.

```
    for(int num1; num1 <= num2; num1++)
        {   
            cout << num1 << " \n";
        }
```

creates a new integer called `num1`, unrelated to the `num1` outside of the for loop. You do not initialize the value of `num1`, but proceed to make comparisons against it.

Remove `int num1` (that is, something like `for(; num1 <= num2; num1++)`) in your for loop and try again.

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you! I changed it to:

for(; num1 <= num2; num1++)

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for(int i = num1; i<= num2; i++)
```

instead of

```
for(int num1; num1 <= num2; num1++)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) I tried that before, but I get a compiler error: warning: statement has no effect.

Comment: @BillyONeal Why would it not work like that? If he prints `i`?

Comment: @talnicolas: Because you changed the semantics of the OP's code. Obstinately he's looking for his `num1` to be changed after execution of the loop, and your modification (taking a copy) doesn't do that. Even if `num1` is discarded after use, you've wasted a variable copying a value that's about to be destroyed anyway. The first clause of a for loop is optional for a reason.

Comment: @BillyONeal Didn't notice that he wanted `num1` to be changed, he just specified that he needed to print a range of value. But no problem, have a nice day.

Comment: In fact, i prefer this answer over the other. Because, it does not change the value of num1. And by looking at the OP's code, it is irrelevant if num1 changes or not...

Answer (score 0):

change this part of code

```
for(int num1; num1 <= num2; num1++)
            {   
                cout << num1 << " \n";
            }
```

to

```
for( ; num1 <= num2; num1++)
            {   
                cout << num1 << " \n";
            }
```